# Error with Case in mysql, where is the error?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'd like to know what's wrong on the following code:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT calldate, dst, billsec, accountcode, disposition, 
                case when cast(substring(dst,4,1), unsigned) <= 5 then
                        billsec/60*%s as total
                else
                        billsec/60*%s as total
                end case
                FROM cdr where calldate >= '%s' and calldate < '%s' and disposition like '%s' and accountcode = '%s' and dst like '%s'""" %(rate_fixo, rate_movel, start_date, end_date, status, accountcode, destino))
```

Tried this way and didn't work:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT calldate, dst, billsec, accountcode, disposition,
    case when cast(substring(dst,4,1), unsigned) <= 5 then 
        billsec/60*%s 
    else 
        billsec/60*%s 
    end as total
    FROM cdr where calldate >= '%s' and calldate < '%s' and disposition like '%s' 
    and accountcode = '%s' and dst like '%s'""" 
    %(rate_fixo, rate_movel, start_date, end_date, status, accountcode, destino))
```

Error:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' unsigned) <= 5 then billsec/60*0.1 else billsec/60*0.2 end as total  FROM cdr w' at line 1")

Comment: what is the error message you get?

Comment: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case as total FROM cdr where calldate >= '2012-09-16' and calldate < '2020-12-12' at line 1")

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has two case statement syntaxes. one for [queries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html), one for [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html). you're using the sproc version in a query, causing the error. There is no 'end case' in the query version:

```
SELECT ..., CASE WHEN ... THEN... END 
                                      ^---no 'case' here
FROM ...
```

--- followup

as well, you can't alias the components of the case - that'd dynamically change the name of the field, depending on how the case's evaluation turns out. You can only alias the ENTIRE case statement:

```
SELECT ..., CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END AS total
                                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

e.g.

```
mysql> select case when 1=1 then 'a' else 'b' end case, 'hello';
                                                  ^^^^---syntax error         
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case, 'hello'' at line 1

mysql> select case when 1=1 then 'a' else 'b' end, 'hello';     
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| case when 1=1 then 'a' else 'b' end | hello |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| a                                   | hello |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select case when 1=1 then 'a' as 'a_val' else 'b' as 'b_val' end, 'hello
';
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^--error  ^^^^^^^^^^^--- error
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as 'a_val' else 'b' as 'b_val' end, 'hello'' at line 1

mysql> select case when 1=1 then 'a' else 'b' end as total, 'hello';           
+-------+-------+
| total | hello |
+-------+-------+
| a     | hello |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: My query now is: cursor.execute("""SELECT calldate, dst, billsec, accountcode, disposition,case when cast(substring(dst,4,1), unsigned) <= 5 then billsec/60*%s else billsec/60*%s end as total  FROM cdr where calldate >= '%s' and calldate < '%s' and disposition like '%s' and accountcode = '%s' and dst like '%s'""" %(rate_fixo, rate_movel, start_date, end_date, status, accountcode, destino))

What's my mistake?

Comment: gah. don't put massive blocks of code into a comment. it's totally unreadable. you can edit your question. and what's the error being spit out now, anyways?

Comment: cast syntax is wrong in your query. should be `CAST(whatever AS newtype)`, as per [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)